Python Filtering
In my application I have a list of films that I want to filter by year  or other criterias. My filters work fine except the year (= variable annee)
In the following code the variable annee becomes {'9', '1'} for video['année'] = 1999
all the other variables have no such problem
def populate_comboboxes_with_filtered_videos(self, filtered_videos):
    genres = set()
    acteurs = set()
    realisateurs = set()
    annees = set()
    langues = set()
    sous_titres = set()
    for video in filtered_videos:
        genres.update(video['genres'])
        acteurs.update(video['acteurs'])
        realisateurs.update(video['réalisateurs'])
        annees.update(video['année'])
        langues.add(video['langue'])
        sous_titres.add(video['sous_titres'])
        ...

Any help for python newbee would be welcome

It sounds as though video['année'] is a string "1999" and not an integer.  You should probably use annees.add instead of annees.update then.

Looks like you are using update() with a single item instead of a collection. Either put the argument in a container, like a list, tuple, etc, eg annees.update([video['année']]) or use add(), as was suggested earlier.

The problem is ambiguous: It's either that you expect video['année'] to be a collection of numbers, and it's not for some reason, or you should actually be using set.add rather than set.update for annees because video['année'] is actually a string. The solution depends on the true intentions of your code

When you use a set .update method it assumes that the item you are inputting is some iterable (e.g., a list-like). So it will iterate through the object you input. For example:
s = set()
s.update('pizza')

#result: s = {'z', 'p', 'i', 'a'}

In contrast if you call update with a list then it will iterate though the list
s = set()
s.update(['pizza'])

#result: s = {'pizza'}

If you are wanting to add to the list on a by-object basis the .add() is preferred as that will add exactly what you input to the set
s = set()
s.add('pizza')

#result: s = {'pizza'}

Do note that using add means that you must input a hashable type and is very different then .update()
s = set()
s.add(['pizza'])

#result: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

s = set()
s.add(('pizza',)) #<-- a hashable iterable 

#result: s = {('pizza',)}

TLDR: Check that your input variables are correct data types to work with the code you have for the result you want

You didn't use set.add anywhere.

Fixed. Errors of quickly answering using copy+paste

Thanks for the answers - I could resolve my problem
